# How to directly query nested field without specify parent field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have next 3 documents in mongodb:

**document 1:**

```
{
    "name": "device1",
    "camera": {
        "number": 3
    }
}
```

**document 2:**

```
{
    "name": "device2",
    "camera": {
        "number": 1
    }
}
```

**document 3:**

```
{
    "name": "device3",
    "wifi": {
        "number": 2
    }
}
```

My aim is to find all devices which modules' number > 1, the module maybe `camera`, `wifi` or others.

I know I can use next to get the device:

```
> db.devices.find({"camera.number":{$gt:1}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f436a3df716cb47d319245e"), "name" : "device1", "camera" : { "number" : 3 } }
> db.devices.find({"wifi.number":{$gt:1}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f436a58f716cb47d3192460"), "name" : "device3", "wifi" : { "number" : 2 } }
```

But it looks I had to add something like "module.number" in query, you know maybe I have a lots of modules, then not so efficient to use `camera.number`, `wifi.number` & `othermodule.number` to find all matched devices. If possible I can have something magic to directly get the device which "has any module's number > 1", I mean no need to specify the parent field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with `find()` method but you can try [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html) method,

- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) will add `device` field, which convert `$$ROOT` object to array in `k` and `v` format using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html)
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) you can match `device.v.number` to your number
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to hide `device` field

```
db.devices.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { device: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $match: { "device.v.number": { $gt: 1 } } },
  { $project: { device: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cQNsKieTyoZ)

---

Another Possible Way with `aggregate()` method,

- match with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html)
- [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) will input `$$ROOT` as `$objectToArray` and inside `in` checks condition if number is null using [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html) then `$add` number in initialValue otherwise add `0`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
              initialValue: 0,
              in: { $add: ["$$value", { $ifNull: ["$$this.v.number", 0] }] }
            }
          },
          1 // add your search number
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WVYZc3X0OK7)

Comment: New to mongodb, allow me sometime to understand, will back soon.

Comment: Okay added reference links pipeline wise.

Comment: Will `{ $addFields: { device: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } }` bring any efficiency issue? Convert document to `k-v` and add `device` as a field?

Comment: I guess it's a trade-off to use this compared to use a predefined `k-v` like another answer mentioned, I will try its performance with my own real data sets, thanks for the information.

Comment: $addFields will add a new field which is generated from root all fields of current document, so might be it will take little more memory, i have added another solution with only match it is better than first one query, you can check efficiency difference of both queries using [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just change your schema.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/npSvVzbnsyk

```
  {
    "name": "device1",
    "modules": [
      {
        "k": "camera",
        "v": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "device2",
    "modules": [
      {
        "k": "wifi",
        "v": 3
      },
      {
        "k": "camera",
        "v": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "device3",
    "modules": [
      {
        "k": "wifi",
        "v": 2
      }
    ]
  }

db.collection.find({"modules.v": 3})
```