# Query object subdocuments for specific key

Tags: mongodb

i have a MongoDB collection done this way

```
{
    features: {
        feature_1: {
            is_enabled: true,
            depends_on: []
        },
        feature_2: {
            is_enabled: true,
            depends_on: []
        }
        feature_3: {
            is_enabled: true,
            depends_on: []
        }
        feature_4: {
            is_enabled: true,
            depends_on: []
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, due to some changes i've done in some of those subdocuments the key depends_on is called dependency_tree, and even whorse, in some docments both keys are present.

Which query should i run to get all documents that have, in at least one of the features, have the dependency_tree key ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Using $or is my last resort, as the feature keys are a lot more of 4, and even worse, not the same for each documents :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to directly query nested field without specify parent field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556589/how-to-directly-query-nested-field-without-specify-parent-field)