# Query on all descendants of node

Tags: mongodb

Given a collection of MongoDb documents with a property "myContacts" like this:

```
  {
       "_id": 123,
       "myContacts" : {            
            "contacts" : {
                "10" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(10),
                    "name" : "c1",
                    "prop" : true
                },
                "20" : {
                    "_id" : NumberLong(20),
                    "name" : "c2"
                },
            }
        }
}
```

I want to select all documents, where at least one contact lacks the "prop" field.
I figured out a general query:

```
db.getCollection('xyz').find({ 'myContacts.contacts.???.prop': { $exists: false } })
```

The problem is that IDs of the contacts are part of the path and I cannot know them ahead. I want sth like `'myContacts.contacts.$anyChild.prop'`, but cannot find sth similar in the mongo docs.

Does it mean there is no way to do it?

PS: I cannot change the document structure, a live app uses it. I've spent some time with Google and my bet it's not possible. I however would like an opinion from people who have experience with Mongo.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/  Your model doesn't support such queries. Use aggregation framework to convert contacts to an array, then query it with regular dot notation.

Comment: this little similar, you just need to understand the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/63557009/8987128

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for helpful comments, this got me going! I could get the results I wanted with:

```
db.getCollection('xyz').aggregate([{$project: {_id:1, contacts:{$objectToArray: "$myContacts.contacts"}}}, {$match: {"contacts.v.prop" : null}}])
```